# controller mvc3 unit test

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing

How to write unit test for

```
public ActionResult Details()
{
    EmployeeDTO employee = this.EmployeeService.GetLoggedInEmployee();
    EmployeeModel model = assembler.ToEmployeeModel(employee);
    model.Title = GetEmployeeNameTitle(employee);
    model.Controller = "LoanProcessor";
    model.SelectedTab = MainNavTabs.LoanProcessor;
    return View(model);
}
```

I have no idea how to solve it.

Comment: Your question cannot be answered without you first answering the following questions: What's `this.EmployeeService`? What's `assembler`? What's the `GetEmployeeNameTitle` method? What's `MainNavTabs.LoanProcessor`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make your code testable, you should inject dependencies to controller (it's not clear from this piece of code if you passing dependencies to controller, or instantiate them directly). Also you should make your controller to depend on abstractions (preferably interfaces) rather than concrete implementations.

EmployeeService should implement this interface:

```
public interface IEmployeeService
{
   EmployeeDTO GetLoggedInEmployee();
   // other methods of service
}
```

Then you make your controller depending on abstraction (only one dependency shown here for sample):

```
public class FooController : Controller
{
    private IEmployeeService _employeeService;

    public FooController(IEmployeeService employeeService)
    {
         _employeeService = employeeService;
    }   
}
```

Now you can mock dependencies and start writing tests for controller (sample with NUnit and Moq):

```
[Test]
public void ShouldProvideEmployeeDetails()
{
    // Arrange
    EmployeeDTO bob = new EmployeDTO("Bob", 42);
    Mock<IEmployeeService> employeeService = new Mock<IEmployeeService>();
    employeeService.Setup(s = s.GetLoggedInEmployee()).Returns(bob);
    FooController controller = new FooController(employeeService.Object);
    // Act
    var result = controller.Details() as ViewResult;
    // Assert
    EmployeeModel model = result.ViewData.Model;
    Assert.That(model.Title, Is.EqualTo("Bob"));
    Assert.That(model.Controller, Is.EqualTo("LoanProcessor"));
}
```

Then write code to pass this test.
You can read more on TDD [here](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Built-in-Unit-Test-for-ASP-NET-MVC-3-in-Visual-Studio-2010-Part-2.aspx).